# using aggregate query to iterate on vf page

Tags: aggregate, repeat

I have the following code:

```
for(table1__c t1 :[Select id,form__c,type__c from table1__c where formation__c=:set_formation limit 10000]){
    //create a map of form,list table1
    if(map_table1_form.containsKey(t1.form__c)){ 
        List<table1__c> lsttable = NULL;
        lsttable = map_table1_form.get(t1.form__c);
        lsttable.add(t1);
        map_table1_form.put(t1.form__c,lsttable);
    }
    else{
        List<table1__c> lsttable= new list<table1__c>();
        lsttable.add(t1);
        map_table1_form.put(t1.form__c,lsttable);
    }
}
```

This map is used on vf page to show the table1 values grouped by form values. Also at the end these values are added to get final sum for all the forms.(I had to skip the idea of wrapper class as that too was eating a lot of heap size).

But I need to refine the code as it has slowed the page load(pdf generation is happening). I was thinking if instead of using the map (which is generated using for loop) , could i use aggregate query to eliminate the for loop. If so how could i repeat over the aggregate query result in the vf page.

Comment: that code should not slow the page generation down as you are only querying 10K records. I would look elsewhere for the problem. Maybe you could tell us about the problem you are facing in detail. Maybe someone could help.